# Proving Lagrange's theorem with homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Let f:G-->H be a homomorphism, where G is a finite group  with identity e1 and H is a finite group with identity e2.

Prove that the order of f(g) is a divisor of g for all g in G.

So I know that f(g) belongs to H. If H was then a subgroup of G, I could use Lagrange's theorem to state that the order of the subgroup is a divisor of the order of the original group G. But then I don't know that H is a subgroup of G. Am I on the right track?

Comment: The statement ought to say: *Prove that the order of $f(g)$ is a divisor of the order of $g$ for all $g$ in $G$*

Answer (score 0):

If $o(g)=m$ then $g^m=e_1$ and $(f(g))^m=f(g^m)=f(e_1)=e_2$ and if $o(f(g))=k$ then also $e_2=(f(g))^k=f(g^k)$.

Now since $k$ is minimal then applying the division's algorithm we can find
$$m=ck+r,$$
where $0\le r<k$ and for some $c,r\in\Bbb Z$.

But also $(f(g))^r=e_2$ and the fact that $k$ is minimal then $r=0$ so $m=ck$, that is $k\mid m$.